# How do you return an array of structs from a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I'm trying to create an array of structs and `fread` file data in to the array inside a helper function. I keep getting `incompatible pointer type` errors when I compile the program. This is my current code:

```
 struct fentry *read_fentries(FILE *fp){
    fentry *files[MAXFILES];

    // EXTRACT FENTRIES AND FNODES FROM FILE
    if ((fread(files, sizeof(fentry), MAXFILES, fp)) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not read file entries\n");
        closefs(fp);
        exit(1);
    }
    return files;
}
```

[image: Terminal Output]

My main question is how can I create an array of structs of a pre-defined size (MAXFILES) and return it from a function so that I can access the struct array inside my `main`. Would I have to allocate memory using `malloc`?

Comment: `files` is an array of pointers. The return type of function is just a pointer of `struct fentry`. You may need to return something like `files[some_index]`. Try returning `files[0]` and it will compile without errors.

Comment: `fentry` is not defined.  Are you using a C++ compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allocate space for it with `malloc` for example, because as you see from the error you returning a pointer to a local address, which is a problem since once you exit this function the `files` array will be freed/non existent. So you returning pointer will point to an invalid memory location.

So do something like this:

```
struct fentry *files = malloc(MAXFILES * sizeof(fentry);
```

Also in this case do not forget to free the allocated memory with `free(*ptr_to_array)` when does not needed anymore.

Comment: I tried changing the second line of the code to malloc it like you suggested. But I am getting the same error (incompatible pointer type, not local variable error).

Comment: Try `struct fentry *files = malloc(MAXFILES * sizeof(fentry);` maybe that what I overlooked here.

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried, it still returned same issue :(

Comment: maxbe type cast here is necessary `struct fentry *files = (stuct fentry*) malloc(MAXFILES * sizeof(fentry);`

Comment: Sorry your first comment was correct. I forgot to add the "struct" keyword in the declaration. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can also return be the value if you wrap the array.

```
#define MAXFILES 50

struct _fentry
{
    FILE *fp;
    int somedata[3];
    double anotherdata[10];
    /* ... */
};

struct fentry
{
    struct _fentry entries[MAXFILES];
};


struct fentry foo()
{
    struct fentry entries;

    /* .... */

    return entries;
}
```